# Keras custom RMSLE metric

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, metrics

How do I implement this metric in Keras? My code below gives the wrong result!
Note that I'm undoing a previous log(x + 1) transformation via exp(x) - 1, also negative predictions are clipped to 0:

```
def rmsle_cust(y_true, y_pred):
    first_log = K.clip(K.exp(y_pred) - 1.0, 0, None)
    second_log = K.clip(K.exp(y_true) - 1.0, 0, None)
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(K.log(first_log + 1.) - K.log(second_log + 1.)), axis=-1)
```

For comparison, here's the standard numpy implementation:

```
def rmsle_cust_py(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
    # undo 1 + log
    y = np.exp(y) - 1
    y_pred = np.exp(y_pred) - 1

    y_pred[y_pred < 0] = 0.0
    to_sum = [(math.log(y_pred[i] + 1) - math.log(y[i] + 1)) ** 2.0 for i,pred in enumerate(y_pred)]
    return (sum(to_sum) * (1.0/len(y))) ** 0.5
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: Setting `axis=0` seems to give a value very close to the correct one, but I'm not sure since all the code I've seem uses `axis=-1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and searched for it, here is what I found

https://www.kaggle.com/jpopham91/rmlse-vectorized

After modified a bit, this seems to work for me,`rmsle_K` method implemented with `Keras` and `TensorFlow`.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def rmsle(y, y0):
    assert len(y) == len(y0)
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power(np.log1p(y)-np.log1p(y0), 2)))

def rmsle_loop(y, y0):
    assert len(y) == len(y0)
    terms_to_sum = [(math.log(y0[i] + 1) - math.log(y[i] + 1)) ** 2.0 for i,pred in enumerate(y0)]
    return (sum(terms_to_sum) * (1.0/len(y))) ** 0.5

def rmsle_K(y, y0):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(tf.log1p(y) - tf.log1p(y0))))

r = rmsle(y=[5, 20, 12], y0=[8, 16, 12])
r1 = rmsle_loop(y=[5, 20, 12], y0=[8, 16, 12])
r2 = rmsle_K(y=[5., 20., 12.], y0=[8., 16., 12.])

print(r)

print(r1)

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(r2))
```

**Result:**

Using TensorFlow backend

```
0.263978210565

0.263978210565

0.263978
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the exp(x) - 1 transformation?

Comment: @Fernando I don't think you need that transformation though https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/RootMeanSquaredLogarithmicError

Comment: I need because my model fits log(x + 1), so I need to transform back via exp(x) - 1, then apply RMSLE.

Comment: Won't minimizing log error also minimize real error, as the log function is a monotonic transformation?

Answer (score 3):

By the use of a list (`to_sum`) in the numpy implementation, I suspect your numpy array has shape `(length,)`.

And on Keras, since you've got different results with `axis=0` and `axis=1`, you probably got some shape like `(length,1)`.

Also, when creating the `to_sum` list, you're using `y[i]` and `y_pred[i]`, which means you're taking elements from the `axis=0` in numpy implementation.

The numpy implementation also sums everything for calculating the mean in `sum(to_sum)`. So, you really don't need to use any `axis` in the `K.mean`.

If you make sure your model's output shape is either `(length,)` or `(length,1)`, you can use just `K.mean(value)` without passing the axis parameter.

Comment: I noticed that, but Keras is giving a slightly different result for the same (y, y_pred) pair. I have no idea why.