# How to add custom metric to keras? (Percent Mean Absolute Error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to add **percent mean absolute error** (pmae) as a custom metric in keras. This is defined as (MAE divided by the mean absolute y-value multiplied by 100). I have tried:

```py
def pmae(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true)) / K.mean(K.abs(y_true)) * 100
...
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(),metrics=[pmae])
```

which runs, but the value is many orders of magnitude off (when I look at `model.history.history.pmae`)

The working numpy version (on a test sample) is:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
pmae = abs(y_pred - y_test).mean() / abs(y_true).mean() * 100
```

I've also tried adding `, axis=-1` to the `K.mean()` calls, with no improvement (as suggested in other stackoverflow answers). Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Resources**

1. The [keras website](https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics) gives mean value of y as an example:

```py
import keras.backend as K

def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred])
```

2. Others have answered on stackoverflow about other custom metrics (eg [Keras custom RMSLE metric](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47582982/11918892) and [how to implement custom metric in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657260/how-to-implement-custom-metric-in-keras)), but the responses there haven't helped me with pmae calculation.

Comment: Can you not use http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.1.1/metrics/#mean_absolute_percentage_error? I think they're the same thing...

Comment: That link refers to MAPE (mean absolute percent error), which is different [mean(abs(percent(error)))].

I'm trying to calculate PMAE, or [percent(mean(abs(error)))], which is less sensitive to large percentages from individual observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare your implementation with the [`mean_absolute_percentage_error`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py#L616) in Keras:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    if not K.is_tensor(y_pred):
        y_pred = K.constant(y_pred)
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
    diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                            K.epsilon(),
                                            None))
    return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
```

Based on this, the following should work for your case:

```
def percent_mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
    if not K.is_tensor(y_pred):
        y_pred = K.constant(y_pred)
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
    diff = K.mean(K.abs((y_pred - y_true)) / K.mean(K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                                           K.epsilon(),
                                                           None)))
    return 100. * K.mean(diff)
```

The main difference to your attempt is that here both `y_true` and `y_pred` are cast to the same datatype and the denominator is at least `K.epsilon()` (which is [set to `1e-7` by default](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/common.py#L9)), so the error does not go to infinity if `y_true` approaches `0`.

Comment: Thanks, this (almost) works. I just needed to remove the "axis=-1" in your last line, otherwise I get the error

"ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension -1 for input with 0 dimensions. for 'metrics/pmae/Mean_2' (op: 'Mean') with input shapes: [], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <-1>." 

Could you explain why this works and what was wrong with my attempted solution?

Comment: Glad that I could help, I removed the wrong `axis=-1`. Without knowing which values you input, it is impossible to tell for certain, but I assume that the key difference is that the denominator cannot become `0` here. It is always at least `K.epsilon()` which is set to `1e-7` by default. This prevents the error from blowing up to infinity if `y_true` is close to `0`.